# play framework WS execution exception [IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x46, /localhost:port :> remote-hostname/remote-ipAddress:remote-port id]]

Tags: playframework

Play application was working fine and suddenly it stopped working.
And I started seeing below exception in browser

Execution exception

`[IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x4628a18a, /ipaddress:port :> remote-hostname/remote-ipaddress:remote-port]]`

In my application I am using WS api to call rest api of remote machine.

Below is the complete stack trash.

```
! @6aj8e9cd9 - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x4628a18a, /ipaddress:port :> remoteHostName/remoteIPaddress:port]]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0x4628a18a, /ipaddress:port :> remotehostname/remoteIPaddress:port]
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.channelClosed(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1352) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:93) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:143) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558) ~[netty.jar:na]
```

I am totally clueless. Looking for your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My bad. It was happening because of one unhandled null pointer exception.

Comment: How did you debug this?